# selenium how to get the value of a tag and display it in a messagebox when it is not a text

Tags: selenium

I am trying to access the value of the following tag in selenium (Lotus)

`<h4>Lotus</h4>`

the fact that it is not a text is returning an empty msgbox when I try to display the attribute of the h4 tag.
Do you guys know what i should do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ***value***. It is the text of ***h4*** tag you are trying to have

You need to have the following code to work with

`selenium.getText("//h4");`

The above stands for `Java` as the programming language